# Best way to query something where a row corresponds to several rows of data in another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So I have two tables, `A` and `B`.

`A` has a primary key `id`.

`B` is effectively a list for entries in `A`. So `B` has the foreign key `id`, but may have several rows for each `id`.

I want to run a single query that gets one row of `A` and all the corresponding rows in `B`.

Right now I'm doing this with an `INNER JOIN` but I'm concerned about performance - the entries in `A` are duplicated on each row in the output in order to correspond with `B`.

Here's an example:

`A
id | blah 
1  | x
2  | y`

`B
id | foo
1  | m
1  | n
1  | o
2  | p`

Also note that `B` may have many columns with relevant data, not just a single `foo` column.

I want to be able to run a `SELECT` that will give me, for `id = 1`, `blah = x` from `A` and `foo = m`, `foo = n`, and `foo = o` from `B`. But unless I'm overthinking it, it seems that a join that returns the following would be quite inefficient, because `x`, which could be potentially quite large, is duplicated over and over (and this also seems somewhat challenging to parse server-side).

`id | blah | foo
1   | x | m
1   | x | n
1   | x | o`

I feel like this is a common enough procedure that it should have an efficient query, but I wasn't able to get the wording down clearly enough to find anything helpful online :(

I'm using PostgreSQL 10 but I imagine the command is probably similar in other query languages.

Comment: use two separate queries

Comment: That's actually what I'm using in production right now, but I'm concerned about potential slowdown from latency on queries. I'm selecting many different ids, so what feels like it could be one query is sometimes 100+ (1 extra query for each id) Is that premature optimization that I shouldn't worry about?

Comment: you can still use two queries to fetch all data for multiple ids by using `IN` instead of `=`

Comment: Oh, so first parse through the first query results and pull the ids, and then query again to pull all the data. That sounds like it should work great, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that worrying about the amount of redundant data in a join result is unnecessary, unless you have evidence that network bandwidth or parsing values on the client are your bottleneck.

**Normally, a single query that returns all results (option 1 below) is best.**

You should run a benchmark and compare these two things:

1. The simple query:

   ```
   SELECT id, a.blah, b.foo
   FROM a JOIN b USING (id);
   ```
2. Two queries, avoiding result redundancy:

   ```
   SELECT a.id, a.blah
   FROM a
   WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM b
       WHERE b.id = a.id);

   SELECT id, b.foo
   FROM a JOIN b USING (id);
   ```

All other approaches must be slower:

- Performing the nested loop join in the application by performing a separate query on `b` for each row found in `a` is madness. It will always perform worse because the overhead for executing a database query (compose a query, send it, parse and process it on the database, send the result back, parse the result) has to be paid for each row in the join result.
- Sending a second query with a large `IN` list of `id`s found in the first query might produce very long statements that take long to parse. Also, such statements are less efficient to execute than the join itself. Essentially, it is a de-optimized version of a hash join.